# ¿como aplicar formato de fecha en una tabla HTML trayendo de un modelo de DJango?

Tags: html, python, django

```
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <!--<th scope="col">ID</th>--!>
        <th WIDTH="80" scope="col">Numero TEC</th>
        <th scope="col">Cliente</th>
        <th scope="col">Breve Descripción del Servicio</th>
        <th scope="col">Status</th>
        <th scope="col">Fecha Servicio</th>
        <th scope="col">Fecha Visita</th>
        <th scope="col">Fecha Cierre</th>
        <th WIDTH="140" scope="col">Opciones</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for ServicioTecnico in servicios %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ServicioTecnico.id}}</td>
        <td>{{ServicioTecnico.clientes}}</td>
        <td>{{ServicioTecnico.descripcion}}</td>
        <td>{{ServicioTecnico.id_status}}</td>
        <td>{{ServicioTecnico.fecha}}</td>
        <td>{{ServicioTecnico.fecha_visita}}</td>
        <td>{{ServicioTecnico.fecha_final}}</td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'editarserviciotecnico' ServicioTecnico.id%}" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Editar</a>  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Ver</button></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Tengo esta tabla, la lleno trayendo de una BD, pero el campo que lleno con fechas me esta llenado con un tipo text y lo necesito con un tipo Date. ¿Como puedo convertir {{ServicioTecnico.fecha}} en un tipo Date para que la tabla se vea una fecha en formato 2022-05-02 que es como sale en la BD.

la tabla que yo tengo esta en HTML, la BD es de un modulo que cree por medio de Django con Python. entonces el Bucle FOR trae del modelo ServicioTecnico el campo fecha y lo muestra en la tabla usando views.py y urls.py. cuando muestro en la tabla el campo fecha me lo muestra como un string mas no como una fecha. se que tengo que hacer una conversión de String a Date pero no la he podido crear.

Comment: En tu BD, ¿Cómo estás guardando la fecha? con que tipo de dato? o pon un ejemplo de como la tienes guardada. Por ejemplo 02 Mayo 2022

Comment: en la BD esta guardada (2022-05-02). en la tabla como la estoy llamando me la muestra 02 Mayo 2022.
Pero quiero verla (2022-05-02)

Comment: No estas diciendo de donde sale **ServicioTecnico**, ni que tipo de lenguaje o plantilla es ese, pues HTML puro no es. Debes incluir las etiquetas en la pregunta correctamente para no generar confusión. Léete [ask], [tour] y [example] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y hacer mejores preguntas y obtener buenas respuestas.  No borres preguntas cuando ya tengas las soluciones sin más (lo digo  por tu anterior pregunta que te he contestado y ahora ni aparece ni has comentado si te ha funcionado mi explicación).

Comment: Hola si tienes razón, la borre porque creo que me dijeron que estaba muy mal formulada y creo que no me estaba haciendo entender. la tabla que yo tengo esta en HTML, la BD es de un modulo que cree por medio de Django con Python. entonces el Bucle FOR trae del modelo ServicioTecnico el campo fecha y lo muestra en la tabla usando views.py y urls.py.
cuando muestro en la tabla el campo fecha me lo muestra como un string mas no como una fecha. se que tengo que hacer una conversión de String a Date pero no la he podido crear.

Comment: Vale, pues eso mismo que has dicho en el comentario lo puedes agregar a la pregunta y obtendras mejores respuestas (lo siento, python no es lo mio y no sabria por donde van los tiros exactamente para ayudarte).  **No crees una nueva pregunta**, edita esta pulsando sobre el enlace [edit] que aparece en gris debajo de la pregunta para agregar esa información, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es mostrarlo en el Template como mismo se muestra en la base de datos entonces cambia:

```
<td>{{ServicioTecnico.fecha}}</td>
```

por

```
<td>{{ServicioTecnico.fecha | date:"Y-m-d"}}</td>
```